# Create a temporary table then using select insert data into it in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've been trying to work with a table that uses multiple joins on a table with 25M records and is just too slow, so the idea is to create a temporary table then insert a smaller amount of data from a query and then run the result. The issue is my Oracle experience is not great from many years ago with SQL I would use a SSIS batch but here I'm finding my way. Can someone please either provide an example I can follow or help with the process of running all these within one run for the desired result.

Comment: There are a  lot of reasons why your original query could be slow, and a lot of potential fixes that could improve performance without resorting to a temporary table. temporary tables will require additional disk i/o and transaction processing, and quite possibly slow you down even more. With many joins, Oracle is likely doing something like this behind the scenes already. What other steps have you taken to tune your query and/or improve the performance of your existing table structure? Please post enough detail (related table and index DDL, query SQL, explain plan, etc.) for us to help.

Comment: Also, "running all these within one run" - do you mean within a single SQL query? If you introduce a temp table to hold intermediate results, that will require multiple SQL statements and transactions. You can't so that in a single SQL statement. You would need to submit a PL/SQL block or call a pipelined PL/SQL function to do something like that. Depending on what you're trying to do with your query, there are likely far more efficient methods you could use to get the desired result.

Comment: I want to run it like SSIS in SQL so I think I need a Pipeline. How do I set that up in Toad which is the tool I'm using?

Comment: A pipelined function is a stored procedure that returns results like a table. It is useful in specific situations where certain calculations need to be performed row-by-row on the fly, or where security is important and table access needs to be indirect. There are likely *far* more efficient ways to achieve what you're trying to do that *could* be done with a single SQL command, or through other pre-processing options like use of materialized views. I would exhaust all options for tuning your original SQL query before looking to solutions that require temp tables or multi-step transactions.